# C++ Pause External Program

Tags: c++, execution

Is it possible by any means to brute force momentally pause the execution of an external program? Or something that archieves a similar effect.

I've seen this beforce, a 3rd party software that once came with my Asus laptop, however Im courious on how they managed it.

Comment: What operating system? There's no way to do this in C++ intrinsically, it depends on the API you have available. Normally it's a bad idea to try and suspend another process, your options are to re-prioritize it or kill it completely. If this other process has some way of signalling that it should stop doing whatever it's doing, that would be another method.

Comment: Windows, however they might have had a driver or something that gave them access to such. But Im still courious.

Comment: Which Windows versions do you need to support? Is it okay if the process becomes "unresponsive" when stopped? Normally this kind of thing is considered to be a little abusive, programmers don't engineer their programs to be hijacked by others, so you may get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: You probably can do this with whatever platform's operating system tools. But it may be more of a hack than something intentionally put in the API.

Comment: Call SetProcessAffinityMask with 0 for a mask.

Answer (score 2):

You can send signals to process. Depending on your operating system, they mean different things. A program which catches a signal may terminate, sleep or continue.

Here is a manual about signals: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node24.html

In short:

Use kill (dont be scared, the functions is just called kill and wont terminate anything on its own) to send a signal to a known process id. You can get process ids in linux with ps aux in terminal. This Linux signal looks promising for you:

```
SIGCONT 19 /* continue a stopped process */

int kill(int pid, int signal)
```

- a system call that send a signal to a process, pid. If pid is greater than zero, the signal is sent to the process whose process ID is equal to pid. If pid is 0, the signal is sent to all processes, except system processes.

I don't know much about Windows SIGNAL Codes, but it should work similar. Don't know if they are handling the signal codes different then Linux.

There is also: signal (int number, functionPointer) to call a function, if your programm gets a specific signal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about bruteforce, but you can probably just set a debug break in a program and that would pause it.

Comment: Running a debug build of something just to do this is extremely wasteful.

Comment: Why would you need to run a debug build to set a breakpoint in a program?

Comment: Yes attaching a debugger to the external program, would do the trick. Another solution could be to suspend all threads in the application like ProcessExplorer/ProcDump is doing while writing minidump.

Comment: Where are you going to put the breakpoint unless you have a debug build? Just some random instruction and hope for the best?